# Convert jQuery code into Mootools

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter, mootools

I have a jQuery code:

```
$('#users').append(users.join('')).filter(function(i) {
     return ids.indexOf(this.id) === -1;
}).remove();
```

How can I rewrite this code using Mootools javascript library?
Thanks.

Full code below:

```
    ...
    success: function(r) {  

        var users   = [],
            ids     = [];   

        for(var i=0; i< r.users.length;i++){
            if(r.users[i]){         
                users.push(_chat.render('user', r.users[i]));   
                ids.push('user-' + r.users[i].name);        
            }
        } 


        $('#users').removeClass('sending2').append(users.join('')).children().filter(function(i) {
             return ids.indexOf(this.id) === -1;
        }).remove();
   }...
```

Comment: what is in the users array and ids?

Comment: Hello, Dimitar! Thanks for the great Mootools extensions. Please check my full code block (success request function).

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what users will contain - assuming elements with an id like `user-name`

```
var users = ["<div id='user-john'>john</div>", "<div id='user-bob'>bob</div>"],
    ids = ['user-john'];


$("users").adopt(new Element('div', {html: users.join('')}).getChildren().filter(function(user){
    return ids.indexOf(user.get('id')) !== -1;  // unless it's another this.id... 
}));
```

Not sure it's the same but should get you started. it only injects the filtered ones. if you want the opposite, reverse the filter to === -1; - it's using a dummy div element to host the dynamic ones from the array and filter them outside the dom, rather than inside, which will be slower.

Comment: Working solution is here: document.id("users").set('html', users.join(''));

Comment: But I would like to add new user to the list of users and next step is to remove not existing users (r.users) from the userlist...using periodical request to the server.